# Is there an aws event that we can subscribe to for a Change Elastic IP event of an EC2 Instance to trigger a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm writing a Lambda query-ec2-instances-eipdetails that will be triggred by an Ec2 Change EIP or whenever somebody runs a

```
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCE
```

Can I create a rule that triggers when any Ec2 instance in the region change IP?

I'm planning to do Something like this

```
aws events put-rule \
    --name EveryChangeEip \    
    --event-pattern "{\"source\":[\"aws.ec2\"],\"detail-type\":[\"Is there an EC2 Instance Change eip?\"]}"
```

for example this does not work since State-change is not triggred

```
aws events put-rule --name "EC2InstanceStateChanges" --event-pattern "{\"source\":[\"aws.ec2\"],\"detail-type\":[\"EC2 Instance State-change Notification\"]}"
```